# Preserve user preferences upon app update

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am using the `Preference` class for storing user settings in my app.

How can I ensure these settings are preserved upon issuing app updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  shared preferences should not get deleted on app updates, they are only deleted if you uninstall and reinstall the app.

Answer (score 1):

On Update, the only thing that gets replaced is the apk. Be sure hat your package Name dos not change, this will probably be seen as a new App by android